# Using viewdeck, while closing leftView chenterView appears but but not reloaded

Tags: objective-c, ios7, viewwillappear, viewdidappear, viewdeck

I'm using `ViewDeck` library to use side panel functionality and it works fine. My application needs the `centerViewController` to be reloaded while I click some button from `LeftViewController`.
and it should be reloaded after appearing the `centerView`.

```
#import TCenterViewController.h

....

- (void)ViewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   // code to reload the view
}
```

And m calling it from `LeftViewController`.

```
[self.viewDeckController.centerController viewDidAppear:NO];
```

Its working. but taking the time to load before the view appears. how can I reduce the delay??

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but in case someone still needs the answer. You need to insert your update code in

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

this method is called every time the scene appears. However, this is not the case with `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: thanks... but that is not the right answer...anyway i somehow managed to reduce the delay.